# How can a react-native component be rendered inside a fetch success response?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to display a badge with the number of properties of each property type. The data from the API is received, but the Badge component doesn't render.

````
countProp = (id) => {

    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/property/' + id).then((data) => data.json())

.then((response) => {

                ```return <Badge value={response.properties.length}/>

            });
    };
````

Thereafter the below function is called inside this `renderItem` method which serves as an array iterator to render the property types:

````
 renderItem = ({item}) => {

   return(

    <View>  
    ....

    ```{this.countProp(item.id)}

    </View>

    )

  }
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to break this out into a separate component and make the api call in componentDidMount something like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class Item extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/property/" + this.props.id)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ length: response.properties.length });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Badge value={this.state.length} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And then use this component passing it the id:

```
import Item from "./path/to/Item.js";

...

<Item id={ 7 } />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save `response.properties.length` in the state, and then access it at `renderItem`.
Something like this:

```
fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/property/' + id).then((data) => data.json())
.then((response) => {
        this.setState({length: response.properties.length});
    });
};
```

At `renderItem`, you can do something like this:

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return(
        <View>  
            <Badge value={this.state.length}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The badge now renders but the value is null, state doesn't seem to update.

Comment: How did you run that first chunk of code? I would put it in a method and execute it inside `componentDidMount`. If it returns a value, then the state will be set and it will be visible in the badge. Not sure what was your approach.

Comment: Yes I put it inside the method "countProp(typeID)", but the result I wanted required that this method should be called inside the "renderItem(typesObject)" method in order to get the number of properties for each TYPE.So calling countProp() inside componentDidMount would not work for me. I hope I explained my approach clearly and again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
countProp = (id) => {
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/property/' + id).then((data) => data.json()).then((response) => {
            this.setState({ length: response.properties.length });
    });
};

renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    this.countProp(item.id);
    return (
        <View>
            <Badge value={this.state.length} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this approach too, but it doesn't fix it, thanks anyways.